# How can I Find a Date Between Two Dates and Return a Holiday?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet that has a list of holidays with their corresponding dates.

I need a formula that will return the name of the holiday (column B) if the date falls between two dates (column D and E).

Here is the [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lv47UneRfA2GStt-_Qp1EOrc_OlNdPHC8Mf5yhUmqmM/edit?usp=sharing):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=if(sumproduct((D2<=$A$2:$A$26)*(E2>=$A$2:$A$26)),"Holiday","")
```

to get which holiday(s) and check multiple occurrences within the same period

```
=iferror(textjoin(" + ",true,unique(query(A:B,"select B where A>=DATE'"&TEXT(D2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and A<=DATE'"&TEXT(E2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' ",0))))
```